# Using OpenVPN for a single window

Tags: 11.10, openvpn

How do I use OpenVPN for only one window/process?

**Example Case Scenario:**

I want to use a US only website on Firefox, but use my ip on the chromium process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way you could do that would be to have a proxy server on the same network (or host) as the OpenVPN server and to configure Firefox to use that proxy. You'll have to ensure that the OpenVPN server only pushes routes to it's own network and doesn't make the VPN the default route.

This is because OpenVPN (and indeed any true VPN) works at a networking level, not a process level.

---

> Please give me steps or a tutorial on how to do that

There is an [official how-to](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid) on installing Squid and [for OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN). For anything detailed you need to provide details of the networking setup of your VPN server so we know what your options are.

At a high level, configure:

1. OpenVPN to use routing, not bridging
2. Squid to accept any client on the subnet you're using for OpenVPN
3. Firefox to use the IP of the OpenVPN server's VPN subnet

Comment: Please give me steps or a tutorial on how to do that